# Does Azure Billing API depends on deployment model?

Tags: azure

Any idea if Azure Billing API depends on the deployment model (RM or Classic?). The
[Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-usage-rate-card-overview) does not mention anything specific about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Neither of them**. The deployment model is related to Azure *resources* that you *provision*. The Billing API is just an *API* that Microsoft offers to pull usage and resource data.